# Kotlin to JavaFX, using java getters in kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

So I have created java getters for several TextFields, now I am trying to use a textfield object called projectName in a kotlin class file, this is what I wrote (where it says projectName, it is highlighted red)

```
fun createData () {
val projectData = projectInformation.projectName
}
```

Here is my java getter for reference

```
TextField projectName = new TextField();
public TextField getProjectName() { return projectName; }
```

I get an error when I try to run the program

```
Kotlin: Unresolved reference: projectName
```

Please do not send me the Java to Kotlin documentation as I have already had a look at it. Now the fix to this is to make my variable static, so

```
static TextField projectName = new TextField();
```

It now works, but does this not defeat the whole purpose of getters? I also tried making the variable private because I was told it could have possibly had visibility conflicts since my TextFields are package-visible.

Just for further information, I am using java and Kotlin to develop an application, I have used these TextFields to create a JavaFX GUI, the logic/backend of the GUI is using Kotlin which will also be used to store information into a database. Gist of my entire program : https://gist.github.com/Jabz259/bbd7a10ba447c955b4481fff9c0ec58e

Comment: Is `projectInformation` an instance of the class within which the `getProjectName()` method is defined?  Why isn't the `projectName` field private?  And since `Static` isn't a keyword in Java (or Kotlin), is that a typo, or is that not Java?

Comment: Yes projectInformation is an instance of a class where getProjectName() is defined, and static is a keyword in Java, it is not in Kotlin however.

Comment: No, `Static` is not a Java keyword; `static` is.  (Case is significant.)  This suggests that you've retyped your example code, instead of copy-and-pasting it.  What other typos might there be?

Comment: Apologies I didn't realise that that there's a difference between Static and static (still got a lot to learn), but I had a look at all my code again and copy and pasted them as well, so I assure you it is correct now. But looking back on the code, I made my TextFields private, but I still cannot get the variable in my kotlin file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the gist you linked

> Yes projectInformation is an instance of a class where getProjectName() is defined

is wrong. It is in fact the class `projectInformation` itself, not an instance of it; like writing

```
val x = String.length
```

instead of

```
val str = "some string"
val x = str.length
```

This would explain why adding `static` works, but that's probably not what you actually want to do.

If you follow naming conventions and use upper camel case for classes/interfaces (e.g. `ProjectInformation` instead of `projectInformation`) this would decrease the chance for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You define a local variable here, which is probably useless:

```
fun createData () {
    val projectData = projectInformation.projectName
}
```

`projectName` sounds alike a `String` to me, but `lateinit` should do the job:

```
lateinit var projectName: TextView
```

And generally speaking, getters and setter work a whole lot different in Kotlin:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html

---

"Kotlin Extensions with synthetic views" (synthetic properties) was never recommend, as they don't work cross-module. `DataBinding` would be the better and suggested approach for what you are trying to accomplish there. See [Why kotlinx synthetic is no longer a recommended practice](https://old.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/ala9p2/why_kotlinx_synthetic_is_no_longer_a_recommended/efdvpkg/).